# XamlToHtml Converter in silverLight

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have created an application in silverlight containing a RichTextBox.

Now, the problem is...I want the **HTML** of the data which is entered in RichTextBox.
RichTextBox.xaml property gives me the xaml for the data in the RichTextBox.
**Now I want to convert this xaml into html.**

PS: I need to write the converter into SilverLight application itself. 
**Not in another class library project.**

Please help, it will be very Helpful.

Comment: Please share your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution,
I used the following **XAML to HTML** converter in my silverlight project.
Thanks

```
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Internal Methods
    //
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #region Internal Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Main entry point for Xaml-to-Html converter.
    /// Converts a xaml string into html string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlString">
    /// Xaml strinng to convert.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Html string produced from a source xaml.
    /// </returns>
    static StringBuilder htmlStringBuilder;
    public static string ConvertXamlToHtml(string xamlString)
    {
        xamlString = "<FlowDocument>" + xamlString + "</FlowDocument>";
        XmlReader xamlReader;

        XmlWriter htmlWriter;
        XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();

        xamlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xamlString));

        htmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        htmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(htmlStringBuilder,ws);

        if (!WriteFlowDocument(xamlReader, htmlWriter))
        {
            return "";
        }
        htmlWriter.Flush();

        string htmlString = htmlStringBuilder.ToString();

        return htmlString;
    }

    #endregion Internal Methods

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Private Methods
    //
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #region Private Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Processes a root level element of XAML (normally it's FlowDocument element).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlReader">
    /// XmlReader for a source xaml.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="htmlWriter">
    /// XmlWriter producing resulting html
    /// </param>
    private static bool WriteFlowDocument(XmlReader xamlReader, XmlWriter htmlWriter)
    {
        if (!ReadNextToken(xamlReader))
        {
            // Xaml content is empty - nothing to convert
            return false;
        }

        if (xamlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Element || xamlReader.Name != "FlowDocument")
        {
            // Root FlowDocument elemet is missing
            return false;
        }

        // Create a buffer StringBuilder for collecting css properties for inline STYLE attributes
        // on every element level (it will be re-initialized on every level).
        StringBuilder inlineStyle = new StringBuilder();

        htmlWriter.WriteStartElement("HTML");
        htmlWriter.WriteStartElement("BODY");

        WriteFormattingProperties(xamlReader, htmlWriter, inlineStyle);

        WriteElementContent(xamlReader, htmlWriter, inlineStyle);

        htmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        htmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads attributes of the current xaml element and converts
    /// them into appropriate html attributes or css styles.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlReader">
    /// XmlReader which is expected to be at XmlNodeType.Element
    /// (opening element tag) position.
    /// The reader will remain at the same level after function complete.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="htmlWriter">
    /// XmlWriter for output html, which is expected to be in
    /// after WriteStartElement state.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="inlineStyle">
    /// String builder for collecting css properties for inline STYLE attribute.
    /// </param>
    private static void WriteFormattingProperties(XmlReader xamlReader, XmlWriter htmlWriter, StringBuilder inlineStyle)
    {
        Debug.Assert(xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element);

        // Clear string builder for the inline style
        inlineStyle.Remove(0, inlineStyle.Length);

        if (!xamlReader.HasAttributes)
        {
            return;
        }

        bool borderSet = false;

        while (xamlReader.MoveToNextAttribute())
        {
            string css = null;

            switch (xamlReader.Name)
            {
                // Character fomatting properties
                // ------------------------------
                case "Background":
                    css = "background-color:" + ParseXamlColor(xamlReader.Value) + ";";
                    break;
                case "FontFamily":
                    css = "font-family:" + xamlReader.Value + ";";
                    break;
                case "FontStyle":
                    css = "font-style:" + xamlReader.Value.ToLower() + ";";
                    break;
                case "FontWeight":
                    css = "font-weight:" + xamlReader.Value.ToLower() + ";";
                    break;
                case "FontStretch":
                    break;
                case "FontSize":
                    css = "font-size:" + xamlReader.Value + ";";
                    break;
                case "Foreground":
                    css = "color:" + ParseXamlColor(xamlReader.Value) + ";";
                    break;
                case "TextDecorations":
                    css = "text-decoration:underline;";
                    break;
                case "TextEffects":
                    break;
                case "Emphasis":
                    break;
                case "StandardLigatures":
                    break;
                case "Variants":
                    break;
                case "Capitals":
                    break;
                case "Fraction":
                    break;

                // Paragraph formatting properties
                // -------------------------------
                case "Padding":
                    css = "padding:" + ParseXamlThickness(xamlReader.Value) + ";";
                    break;
                case "Margin":
                    css = "margin:" + ParseXamlThickness(xamlReader.Value) + ";";
                    break;
                case "BorderThickness":
                    css = "border-width:" + ParseXamlThickness(xamlReader.Value) + ";";
                    borderSet = true;
                    break;
                case "BorderBrush":
                    css = "border-color:" + ParseXamlColor(xamlReader.Value) + ";";
                    borderSet = true;
                    break;
                case "LineHeight":
                    break;
                case "TextIndent":
                    css = "text-indent:" + xamlReader.Value + ";";
                    break;
                case "TextAlignment":
                    css = "text-align:" + xamlReader.Value + ";";
                    break;
                case "IsKeptTogether":
                    break;
                case "IsKeptWithNext":
                    break;
                case "ColumnBreakBefore":
                    break;
                case "PageBreakBefore":
                    break;
                case "FlowDirection":
                    break;

                // Table attributes
                // ----------------
                case "Width":
                    css = "width:" + xamlReader.Value + ";";
                    break;
                case "ColumnSpan":
                    htmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("COLSPAN", xamlReader.Value);
                    break;
                case "RowSpan":
                    htmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("ROWSPAN", xamlReader.Value);
                    break;
            }

            if (css != null)
            {
                inlineStyle.Append(css);
            }
        }

        if (borderSet)
        {
            inlineStyle.Append("border-style:solid;mso-element:para-border-div;");
        }

        // Return the xamlReader back to element level
        xamlReader.MoveToElement();
        Debug.Assert(xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element);
    }

    private static string ParseXamlColor(string color)
    {
        if (color.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            // Remove transparancy value
            color = "#" + color.Substring(3);
        }
        return color;
    }

    private static string ParseXamlThickness(string thickness)
    {
        string[] values = thickness.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            double value;
            if (double.TryParse(values[i], out value))
            {
                values[i] = Math.Ceiling(value).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                values[i] = "1";
            }
        }

        string cssThickness;
        switch (values.Length)
        {
            case 1:
                cssThickness = thickness;
                break;
            case 2:
                cssThickness = values[1] + " " + values[0];
                break;
            case 4:
                cssThickness = values[1] + " " + values[2] + " " + values[3] + " " + values[0];
                break;
            default:
                cssThickness = values[0];
                break;
        }

        return cssThickness;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads a content of current xaml element, converts it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlReader">
    /// XmlReader which is expected to be at XmlNodeType.Element
    /// (opening element tag) position.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="htmlWriter">
    /// May be null, in which case we are skipping the xaml element;
    /// witout producing any output to html.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="inlineStyle">
    /// StringBuilder used for collecting css properties for inline STYLE attribute.
    /// </param>
    private static void WriteElementContent(XmlReader xamlReader, XmlWriter htmlWriter, StringBuilder inlineStyle)
    {
        Debug.Assert(xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element);

        bool elementContentStarted = false;

        if (xamlReader.IsEmptyElement)
        {
            if (htmlWriter != null && !elementContentStarted && inlineStyle.Length > 0)
            {
                // Output STYLE attribute and clear inlineStyle buffer.
                htmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("STYLE", inlineStyle.ToString());
                inlineStyle.Remove(0, inlineStyle.Length);
            }
            elementContentStarted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            while (ReadNextToken(xamlReader) && xamlReader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            {
                switch (xamlReader.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        if (xamlReader.Name.Contains("."))
                        {
                            AddComplexProperty(xamlReader, inlineStyle);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (htmlWriter != null && !elementContentStarted && inlineStyle.Length > 0)
                            {
                                // Output STYLE attribute and clear inlineStyle buffer.
                                htmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("STYLE", inlineStyle.ToString());
                                inlineStyle.Remove(0, inlineStyle.Length);
                            }
                            elementContentStarted = true;
                            WriteElement(xamlReader, htmlWriter, inlineStyle);
                        }
                        Debug.Assert(xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement || xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xamlReader.IsEmptyElement);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                        if (htmlWriter != null)
                        {
                            if (!elementContentStarted && inlineStyle.Length > 0)
                            {
                                htmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("STYLE", inlineStyle.ToString());
                            }
                            htmlWriter.WriteComment(xamlReader.Value);
                        }
                        elementContentStarted = true;
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                        if (htmlWriter != null)
                        {
                            if (!elementContentStarted && inlineStyle.Length > 0)
                            {
                                htmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("STYLE", inlineStyle.ToString());
                            }
                            htmlWriter.WriteString(xamlReader.Value);
                        }
                        elementContentStarted = true;
                        break;
                }
            }

            Debug.Assert(xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Conberts an element notation of complex property into
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlReader">
    /// On entry this XmlReader must be on Element start tag;
    /// on exit - on EndElement tag.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="inlineStyle">
    /// StringBuilder containing a value for STYLE attribute.
    /// </param>
    private static void AddComplexProperty(XmlReader xamlReader, StringBuilder inlineStyle)
    {
        Debug.Assert(xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element);

        if (inlineStyle != null && xamlReader.Name.EndsWith(".TextDecorations"))
        {
            inlineStyle.Append("text-decoration:underline;");
        }

        // Skip the element representing the complex property
        WriteElementContent(xamlReader, /*htmlWriter:*/null, /*inlineStyle:*/null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a xaml element into an appropriate html element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlReader">
    /// On entry this XmlReader must be on Element start tag;
    /// on exit - on EndElement tag.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="htmlWriter">
    /// May be null, in which case we are skipping xaml content
    /// without producing any html output
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="inlineStyle">
    /// StringBuilder used for collecting css properties for inline STYLE attributes on every level.
    /// </param>
    private static void WriteElement(XmlReader xamlReader, XmlWriter htmlWriter, StringBuilder inlineStyle)
    {
        Debug.Assert(xamlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element);

        if (htmlWriter == null)
        {
            // Skipping mode; recurse into the xaml element without any output
            WriteElementContent(xamlReader, /*htmlWriter:*/null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            string htmlElementName = null;

            switch (xamlReader.Name)
            {
                case "Run":
                case "Span":
                    htmlElementName = "SPAN";
                    break;
                case "InlineUIContainer":
                    htmlElementName = "SPAN";
                    break;
                case "Bold":
                    htmlElementName = "B";
                    break;
                case "Italic":
                    htmlElementName = "I";
                    break;
                case "Paragraph":
                    htmlElementName = "P";
                    break;
                case "BlockUIContainer":
                    htmlElementName = "DIV";
                    break;
                case "Section":
                    htmlElementName = "DIV";
                    break;
                case "Table":
                    htmlElementName = "TABLE";
                    break;
                case "TableColumn":
                    htmlElementName = "COL";
                    break;
                case "TableRowGroup":
                    htmlElementName = "TBODY";
                    break;
                case "TableRow":
                    htmlElementName = "TR";
                    break;
                case "TableCell":
                    htmlElementName = "TD";
                    break;
                case "List":
                    string marker = xamlReader.GetAttribute("MarkerStyle");
                    if (marker == null || marker == "None" || marker == "Disc" || marker == "Circle" || marker == "Square" || marker == "Box")
                    {
                        htmlElementName = "UL";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        htmlElementName = "OL";
                    }
                    break;
                case "ListItem":
                    htmlElementName = "LI";
                    break;
                default:
                    htmlElementName = null; // Ignore the element
                    break;
            }

            if (htmlWriter != null && htmlElementName != null)
            {
                htmlWriter.WriteStartElement(htmlElementName);

                WriteFormattingProperties(xamlReader, htmlWriter, inlineStyle);

                WriteElementContent(xamlReader, htmlWriter, inlineStyle);

                htmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            }
            else
            {
                // Skip this unrecognized xaml element
                WriteElementContent(xamlReader, /*htmlWriter:*/null, null);
            }
        }
    }

    // Reader advance helpers
    // ----------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads several items from xamlReader skipping all non-significant stuff.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xamlReader">
    /// XmlReader from tokens are being read.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// True if new token is available; false if end of stream reached.
    /// </returns>
    private static bool ReadNextToken(XmlReader xamlReader)
    {
        while (xamlReader.Read())
        {
            Debug.Assert(xamlReader.ReadState == ReadState.Interactive, "Reader is expected to be in Interactive state (" + xamlReader.ReadState + ")");
            switch (xamlReader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                case XmlNodeType.None:
                case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
                    return true;

                case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
                    if (xamlReader.XmlSpace == XmlSpace.Preserve)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    // ignore insignificant whitespace
                    break;

                case XmlNodeType.EndEntity:
                case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
                    //  Implement entity reading
                    //xamlReader.ResolveEntity();
                    //xamlReader.Read();
                    //ReadChildNodes( parent, parentBaseUri, xamlReader, positionInfo);
                    break; // for now we ignore entities as insignificant stuff

                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    return true;
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                case XmlNodeType.DocumentType:
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                default:
                    // Ignorable stuff
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    #endregion Private Methods

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Private Fields
    //
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

    #region Private Fields

    #endregion Private Fields
```